# How can I pass a URL down to a component through a prop and HTML tag to decouple the front end

Tags: reactjs, json, domain-driven-design, react-props

I am making my first personal website with ReactJS, being normally a back end kind of guy. I'm just starting to work with systems of software and have been inspired  by Domain Driven Design. Please forgive the basic nature of my question.

I am attracted to React because of it's use of props to handle data in a decoupled way.

As I build up the site, I notice that my code is becoming very cluttered with lots of URLs buried in html tags. I'm worried that one day, I may need to change them.

I'd like to decouple this and instead pass the URLs from a JSON file into a Prop.

What are the best practices for accomplishing this

Here's an example of my code.

```
<div className="tp-minimal__design-thumb" style={{ **backgroundImage: `url(assets/img/banner/hero-banner.JPG)`,** backgroundPosition: 'center', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', backgroundSize: 'cover' }}></div>
```

How can I get this to accept data from a heirachical JSON Structure like this?

```
const imageData = {
    "home": {
            HeroAreaHome: "url(assets/img/banner/hero-banner.JPG)"
        }
}``
```

I'd like to pass the url down to this (PSEUDO-CODE):

```
import imageData from "../../data/imageData"

<div className="tp-minimal__design-thumb" style={{ **backgroundImage: `{imageData.home.HeroAreaHome}** backgroundPosition: 'center', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', backgroundSize: 'cover' }}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass a variable into jsx using template literals. Something like this should work for you:

```
<div className="tp-minimal__design-thumb" style={{ backgroundImage: `${imageData.home.HeroAreaHome}`, backgroundPosition: 'center', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', backgroundSize: 'cover' }}></div>
```

Also, this component is not using react props to pass the `imageData` around since the data is moved around via a regular export and import. To utilize react props, you would need to pass the variable down when the component is instantiated in a parent component. That pattern looks something like this:

Parent Component:

```
import DesignThumb from './path-to-component'
import imageData from "../../data/imageData"

function ParentComponent() {

  return {
    <>
      <DesignThumb backgroundImage={imageData.home.HeroAreaHome} />
    </>
  }
}
```

Child Component:

```
export default function ChildComponent({backgroundImage}) {

  return <div className="tp-minimal__design-thumb" style={{ backgroundImage: `${backgroundImage}` backgroundPosition: 'center', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', backgroundSize: 'cover' }}></div>
}
```

If the background image won't change, then exporting/importing the imageData is a good pattern to utilize instead of using props. The above code is just an example of what utilizing react props would look like.

Comment: Wow! thank you @cdallava so much for responding. I'm going to take a look at it